# Java localizing number formatting

Tags: java, swing, localization, number-formatting

Java uses period in decimals, e.g. 1/2 = 0.5

Is there any way to make it use comma instead, as in 1/2 = 0,5? And not to use comma for thousands (as in one hundred thousand = 100,000) but use space instead (100 000)?

When it comes to output I suppose I could use all sorts of string format functions, but the problem is input (JTable). Some columns require Double format so users must enter something like 45.5 and in these parts they are used to 45,5 :) Thanks in advance

**Update:**

I tried using myTable.setDefaultLocale(Locale.Germany); but it didnt work. I also did Locale.setDefault(Locale.Germany); @ main function and it did work but in rather silly way: while cell is in editing mode, you must enter dot as normal, i.e. 45.5 but **after** you hit enter to confirm changes, it is displayed as comma: 45,5. I mean it uses comma only for display purposes, but when editing its still same ol' dot.

Is there any way to fix it *without* writing custom table model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Thus, you basically want to *convert* a **localized** `String` representation supposedly in a numerical format into a `Number/BigDecimal` and vice versa?</strike>

There you have the [`java.text.DecimalFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) for. To learn more, consult [Sun's own tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) about the subject.

To localize your Swing application, use [`JComponent#setDefaultLocale()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setDefaultLocale%28java.util.Locale%29). E.g.

```
JComponent.setDefaultLocale(Locale.GERMANY);
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that my table column accepts Double values only, and Double Java-style means USA/Canadian number formatting. I could make it accept String instead of Double and then parse/validate it manually, but isn't there a simpler solution? Something like SetGlobalLocale(Locale.German); and suddenly Java knows that 12,20 is a valid Double value so I dont need to change anything in my table... something like that? :)

Comment: I see, you're using Swing. I updated my answer (and the tags of this question).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I believe this is what I need! So far I got it working, of sorts, its far better than nothing but something is still not exactly right. I updated original question if you have some time to look at it

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Formatting and Parsing a Number for a Locale](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/Numbers.html):

> ```
> // Format for CANADA locale
> Locale locale = Locale.CANADA;
> String string = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale).format(-1234.56); // -1,234.56
>
> // Format for GERMAN locale
> locale = Locale.GERMAN;
> string = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale).format(-1234.56); // -1.234,56
>
> // Format for the default locale
> string = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(-1234.56);
>
>
> // Parse a GERMAN number
> try {
>     Number number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale.GERMAN).parse("-1.234,56");
>     if (number instanceof Long) {
>         // Long value
>     } else {
>         // Double value
>     }
> } catch (ParseException e) {
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

To process the input correctly, you can implement your own TableModel and overwrite the setValueAt method.